# ACF get sub_field of repeater FROM a parent page

Tags: wordpress, field, repeater, parent, advanced-custom-fields

I try to implant this

```
- Page A0 (images + texts)
-- Page A1
-- Page A1
---Page A2
```

In page A1 & A2, I need to retrieves galerie and texts from a group of field.
If I use a normal field, not in a goup, I achieve this... But I need to stay in a group field.

```
 <?php
    $post_ID = get_the_ID();
    $parentpost_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );
    $images_images = get_sub_field( "images", $parentpost_id ); //use parents-post field: "broschuren-download"
     ?>

<div class="hero__image-wrapper <?php if (count ($images_images) > 1) { echo "heroslide" ;} ?> ">
       <?php if ( $images_images ) :  ?>
           <?php foreach ( $images_images as $images_image ): ?>
               <img class="hero__image fit-cover" src="<?php echo $images_image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images_image['alt']; ?>" />
           <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_sub_field()` function only works within a `have_rows()` loop that you run on the parent field. If you still want to use `get_sub_field()`, you would have to do something like this:

```
<?php
$post_ID = get_the_ID();
$parentpost_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );

if( have_rows('broschuren-download', $parentpost_id) ): while( have_rows('broschuren-download', $parentpost_id) ): the_row();

$images_images = get_sub_field('images');

if ( $images_images ):
?>
    <div class="hero__image-wrapper <?php if (count ($images_images) > 1) { echo 'heroslide'; } ?>">
        <?php foreach( $images_images as $images_image ): ?>
        <img class="hero__image fit-cover" src="<?php echo $images_image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images_image['alt']; ?>" />
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php 
endif;
endwhile; endif; 
?>
```